# Enforcing desired relationship between template function parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm working on improving an in-house messaging library, designed to send messages internally within our applications, and to external consumers. A message consists of a `MessageType` (`enum class`) and some data (`struct`). Each `MessageType::` corresponds to a particular data type (e.g., `MessageType::TypeA` will always contain `Foo`). However, multiple message types could use the same struct (e.g., `MessageType::TypeM` could also use `Foo`).

We have a class that can send messages. Our previous implementation of the message sender class defines a method for each type:

```
SendMessageTypeA(Foo data)
SendMessageTypeB(Bar data)
SendMessageTypeM(Foo data)
```

When there are lots of messages, this can result in a lot of code duplication (the method body is essentially the same, with the exception of the different parameter types).

I've implemented a new method:

```
template<typename structType>
void Send(MessageType msgType, const structType & messageData)
```

This single method can send any message, depending on the appropriate template parameter being provided. Note that the `MessageType` is always known at compile time.

The problem is that this new method does not enforce the relationship between `MessageType` and `struct`. For example, `Send<Foo>(MessageType::TypeB, data)` will compile, even though `MessageType::TypeB` should contain `Bar`. The mismatch will be detected at runtime, but I'd like to make it a compile time error.

I'm not sure how to achieve this. I've considered:

1. Declaring all the `SendMessageX()` methods, and use them to call `Send<MessageX>()`. This does reduce the duplication, but I still have to create a new method every time a message is defined.
2. Attempting to use `static_assert` to catch the mismatch. I'm not sure how to map `MessageType`s to their desired `struct`.
3. I'm barking up the wrong tree

Comment: Do you know the message enums at compile time?

Comment: Yes, the association is known at compile time

Comment: Not the association, the values that you're calling `Send()` with.

Comment: Yes, I know the type of every sent message at compile time

Comment: I mean... is it always possible for you to call `Send<TypeA>(data)`?

Comment: Reverse-engineering your answer, yes, I can make the enum a compile-time constant. The values never change during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can lift the enum to a compile time constant, then it's possible:

```
template <MessageType E, class Data>
void Send(Data const& ) { ... }
```

We can create a class template, specialized on each enum with what that enum expects:

```
template <MessageType E> struct expected_type;
template <> struct expected_type<MessageType::TypeA> { using type = Foo; };
template <> struct expected_type<MessageType::TypeB> { using type = Bar; };
template <> struct expected_type<MessageType::TypeM> { using type = Foo; };

template <MessageType E>
using expected_type_t = typename expected_type<E>::type;
```

And then we can use that to just write that static assert:

```
template <MessageType E, class Data>
void Send(Data const& ) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<Data, expected_type_t<E>>{}, "!");
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, could use that class template to set the `Data` type directly:

```
template <MessageType E>
void Send(expected_type_t<E> const& ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Forgive the ignorance, but what do you mean by "lift the enum to a compile time constant"? That implies an enum can be defined at run time. How would that work?

Comment: @Michael An enum value can be determined at runtime. We need it at compile time though.

Comment: You should turn the ellipsis on the final code segment into a comment to keep consistency with the previous code segment.

Comment: This approach works well, because expected_type_t<> is useful in other situations to determine the data type.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another version which I think it is clearer and can match multiple types between message and data.

```
template<typename MT, typename DT>
struct CompitableCheck;
// only declare type pairs you want. A simple macro wrapping it is better
template<>
struct CompitableCheck<MsgTypeA, Bar> { static const bool value = true; };
template<>
struct CompitableCheck<MsgTypeA, Foo> { static const bool value = true; };
template<>   // allow one-to-many map, TypeA -> Foo && TypeA -> Bar.
struct CompitableCheck<MsgTypeA, Bar> { static const bool value = true; };

// here goes the final function
template<typename MT, typename DT, 
         typename = typename std::enable_if<CompitableCheck<MT, DT>::value>>::type
void Send(MT msgType, const DT & messageData) { /* send it */ }
```